# $T:F^n \to F $be linear.show that there exist v$ \in F^n$ s.t Tu=u.v for all u$ \in F^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:F^n \to F$ be linear. Show that there exist $v\in F^n: Tu=u\cdot v \forall u\in F^n$

Need suggestions.

Comment: This is the Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: No, it is not because Hilbert spaces are infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T(e_{i})=a_{i}$, i=1...n, $e_{i}=(0,..,1,...0)$, 1 is i-th. Then

Since T is linear, one has $T(x_{1},...,x_{n})$=$x_{1}T(e_{1})+...+x_{n}T(e_{n})$=$x_{1}a_{1}+...+x_{n}a_{n}$=u.v where $v=(a_{1},...,a_{n}), u=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$.