# isomorphism of vector spaces of linear transformation and $m\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

let $V(F^n,F^m)$  be  the   vector space of all linear transformations from $F^n$ to $F^m$. prove that it is isomorphic to $M_{m\times n}$.

need suggestions.

Comment: Use [this fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424177/tfn-to-f-be-linear-show-that-there-exist-v-in-fn-s-t-tu-u-v-for-all-u)  and split functions into thieri components.

Comment: Do  you  already  know  that  every  linear  transformation  is  represented  by  a  matrix  and  that  every  matrix  represents  a  linear  transformation ? If  you  do ,  then  you  easily  see  the  bijection . Now  look  at  the relation  between  matrix multiplication  and  composition  of  linear  transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to think of an isomorphism. Say $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $F^n$.  Define $g:V(F^N,F^M) \longrightarrow M_{m\times n}$ by  $g(v) =[v(e_1),...,v(e_n)]$ for $v\in V(F^N,F^M)$ You should be able to show that g is linear and bijective so is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think it's not obvious that $g$ is surjective. How do I know that there exists a $v\in V(F^N,F^M)$ such that $g(v) = A$ for some $m\times n$ matrix $A$?